# Issues with Mule ESB collection-aggregator processing

Tags: mule

A simplified version of the process I am trying to accomplish is that I will have sets of files which should be processed, in order, and only as complete sets.  For proof of concept, I have created a flow to collect a set of two files named as "File1*YYMMDD*.txt" and "File2*YYMMDD*.txt" which will constitute a set for date *YYMMDD*.  I use a file inbound-endpoint to watch for files and use the date portion of the name to define a correlation ID. A collection-aggregator then groups these into a set of 2 and a file outbound then dispatched the files from the set:

```
<configuration> 
    <default-threading-profile doThreading="false" />
</configuration>

<flow name="Aggregator">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="G:/SourceDir" moveToDirectory="G:/SourceDir/Archive" 
                        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="get-working-files" 
                        pollingFrequency="5000" fileAge="600000">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="File1(.*).txt|File2(.*).txt" caseSensitive="false"/>
        <message-properties-transformer>
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2" />
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" 
                    value="#[message.inboundProperties
                                    .originalFilename
                                    .substring(5, message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.lastIndexOf('.'))]"  />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <collection-aggregator timeout="86400000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator">
    </collection-aggregator>  

    <foreach doc:name="For Each"> 
        <logger message="Processing: #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" level="INFO" 
                doc:name="Some process"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Destination" 
                outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd.HHmmss].#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" 
                path="G:/DestDir"/>
    </foreach>  
</flow>
```

The issues I have are two-fold.

1) If I have only one file from the set, say File2150102.txt, the flow correctly identifies the set is incomplete and waits.  After about 1 minute, the file again has a lock put on it and is accepted as the second file in the collection.  The file is processed through the outbound endpoint and archived, and then this process is attempted again for the file a second time and fails as the file has already been removed:

> INFO  2015-07-14 11:19:51,205 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: G:\SourceDir\File2150102.txt
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,241 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: G:\SourceDir\File2150102.txt
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,273 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Processing: File2150102.txt
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,304 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.452370795'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,304 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.452370795'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,320 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: G:\DestDir\20150714.112101.File2150102.txt
>     WARN  2015-07-14 11:21:01,336 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream: Failed to move file from G:\SourceDir\File2150102.txt to G:\SourceDir\archive\File2150102.txt
>
> INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,336 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Processing: File2150102.txt
>     INFO  2015-07-14 11:21:01,336 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: G:\DestDir\20150714.112101.File2150102.txt
>     WARN  2015-07-14 11:21:01,476 [[fileset].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Failure trying to remove file G:\SourceDir\File2150102.txt from list of files under processing

I can find no setting which is controlling this iteration of grabbing the file again, my polling frequency is set at 5 seconds, I require a file age of 10 minutes, and gave the collection timeout a very long period of 10 days so it should sit and wait until another file is found, but I do not want it picking up the same file a second time.

2) In a more complex case, I have files: File1150201.txt, File2150201.txt, File1150202.txt, File1150203.txt, and File2150203.txt in the directory.  The flow starts grabbing files, correctly finds and processes the set for "150201" and dispatches it.  It finds the file for 150202, recognizes it needs the second file and does not process it.  It then finds the complete set for "150203" and does process it.  I need for it to not process this set until the "150202" set has been processed.  Can someone tell me how to get it to wait on the incomplete set and not continue with other sets?  I have the correct processing order, just not the ability to wait for the missing file and keep sets in sequence if there is an incomplete set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand it correctly, but for your issue 1, the matching (and waiting for the incomplete sets) is working for me with the below test flow --

```
 <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File">
        <file:expression-filename-parser />
    </file:connector>
    <file:connector name="File1" autoDelete="false" outputAppend="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <vm:connector name="VM" validateConnections="true" doc:name="VM">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"></receiver-threading-profile>
    </vm:connector>
    <flow name="fileaggreFlow2" doc:name="fileaggreFlow2">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\InFile" moveToDirectory="C:\InFile\Archive" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File" doc:name="File">

        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <message-properties-transformer overwrite="true" doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.substring(5,13)]"/>
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2"/>
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.substring(0,5)]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="Merge" doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM"/>
    </flow>


    <flow name="fileaggreFlow1" doc:name="fileaggreFlow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="Merge" doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <collection-aggregator timeout="1000000" failOnTimeout="true" storePrefix="#[MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <foreach doc:name="For Each">
                <logger message="Processing: #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" level="INFO" doc:name="Some process"/>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\TestFile" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.substring(5,17)]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File1" doc:name="Destination"/>
            </foreach>
        </processor-chain>
    </flow>
```

It would help if you could post the complete flow. My file names are File120150107.txt (and so on...)

Comment: Sorry, I had the full flow in place, but missed that I had a formatting error that cause part to not show up.  I will compare some of what you did and mine and see if it makes a difference for me.

Comment: With as new as I am to mule I will need to work through a bit on why you did some of what you did, but the way you broke into two flows and used the VM endpoints eliminates issue 1, thank you!  I tried to do the process with a single flow which did not dispatch the file from the source until complete which left it available to be picked up a 2nd time.  Your layout removes it to archive.  The second issue if still a problem but I will work with it some more and re-post it trying to be clear if (when) I need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is just because you made the failOnTimeout = 'false'. Make it as 'True'

```
    <collection-aggregator timeout="86400000" failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator">
```

.

It will wait for the files ( 2 or 3 files, based on your requirement) until it reached the specific time ( Here, 86400000). Once it exceed, it will fail.

In your case( FailOnTime= 'False'), for example. If you try sending some 4 files. Within the time if only 2 files are received. Incomplete file will be processed ( It wont wait for remaining 2 files).

Try to check how many files you are planning to process, and how long it will take to process ( example:4 files), adjust the time accordingly.

Comment: Have switched between false and true on failOnTimeout with no effect on this issue.  My understanding of this flag is strictly on if failing to get a complete set of files generates an exception or if they are treated as a full set and processed.  I put a very long timeout which should prevent this from even being a factor. It was one of my first thoughts as well.